# how to request the url in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying get the json data from url example.com and pass that to my index.html. How can I do that. It's not working. I want to update data every 5 second file index.html.
app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var https = require('https');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');
   //How to use req object ?

});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('A user connected');


   setInterval(function() {
    urlString = "https://example.com/trip?trip_id=1234";

        $.get(urlString, function(data, status){
            console.log('data');
         })

   socket.send('');
   }, 4000);

   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
   socket.on('message', function(data){document.write(data)});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing a number of things wrong:

1. `$.get()` doesn't run on the server.  That's client-side jQuery code
2. You should create one `setInterval()` on your server, not a new one for each client connection
3. You can then just broadcast the results to all connected clients
4. If you `document.write()` in the client after the page is loaded, it just clears your original document so you want to append info to the DOM, not use `document.write()`.
5. When you send data with socket.io, you send a message name and some data `.emit(someMessage, someData)`.

Here's one way to do your code:

```
// server.js
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const request = require('request');


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');
});

// create one and only one interval
setInterval(function() {
  let urlString = "https://example.com/trip?trip_id=1234";

  request(urlString, function(err, response, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error on request", err);
    } else {
      console.log('data');
      // send to all connected clients
      io.emit('message', data);
    }
  });

}, 5000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('A user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


// index.html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();
socket.on('message', function(data){
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = data;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
</script>
```